# Fit Curve Method

Tags: regression, overfitting, curve-fitting

The data look simple, but I want to model **t+400** data (as **t** is the current time).

## Data looks like this:

[image: Text]

## Simple lm:

```
#r
y=my_vector[(401):length(my_vector)]
x=my_vector[(1  ):(length(my_vector)-400)]

    model1=lm(y~x)
plot(y,type = "l")
lines(model1$fitted.values,type = "l",col="white")
```

### Plot

[image: Text]

I tried to add for example 99 more previous values, but the fit is really bad.

Tried "data points" methods like ar ma, but no good

( I guess data are more like curves, than data points )

I tried using poly in the `lm` model. It looks very nice in terms of curve design, but the distance of fit and y remain bad.

## Question

Can anybody help, with how to model/fit this type of data (in R language)?

Thanks a lot

## Link to data:

Columns

*t-row number (can be ignored*

x-data,number ("double")

https://www.dropbox.com/s/aprykm9x9kue65d/my_data.csv?dl=0

## Bounty edit

How to model this kind of data (to obtain t+400 point), doable in R, which gives a result better than the fit mentioned above?

There is no additional info like timestamps or external regressors etc, only a single vector.

*(my guess is, that data are very simple/fluent like changing waves, like spectral analysis/fourier things but I dont know how to model it, maybe its even more question for math department to obtain these kind of data behaviour, all good ideas/models helpful)*

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you're really not describing what you want to do here; just what you are already doing, and frankly, none of it makes any sense. Explain **why** you're choosing x and y as you do, what the goal of this is. You're using a function that fits a *linear* model - from where does the assumption come any of this is linear? How many dimensions do you actually have in the problem you're trying to solve? All of this is enigmatic.

Comment: @MarcusMüller hello, by dimensions,, its 1 vector, just "float" numbers..goal is to obtain 1 data, 400 points from now (current t)... i dont know, what kind of construction, and which parameters are able to grasp the data. i tried simple time series model types like ets, ar ma, nnetar etc, but these models, are for point data, but i need t+400, so 399 previous data are missing..this could be modelling variance, but again these models model variance as 1 point, while i feel/see there is many information(s) (399) between each data point .. i tried simple "poly", but coulndt bend it correctly : )

Comment: yes, but you can't go "model shopping"; you can *always* find a model with enough parameters to fit your data, and it tells you exactly nothing about the data – just about your ability of finding models. So, what *is* your data? Where does it come from? For which reason are you analyzing it?

Comment: look, i am thankful if you want to help .. you seems asking for solution, as i was happy to have it too .. no additional information are available, its 1 vector, t+400 point needed to be "found/model", i cant share more, but "data speak by itself" is enough, im not extra profesional to grasp structure relationship from it, thats why i ask those who do :-) what i tried is mentioned, bad fit .. are you familiar with similar data structure, or have some helpful idea, or you can point of what kind/type model is initialy guess.. im grateful for any tips, link to data is provided at the bottom

Comment: well with no information to aid modelling, no modelling is possible. Your problem has no good solution with this lack of information, sorry.

Comment: @MarcusMüller oki :-)  Anybody feel free to ask if interested :-)

Answer (score 2):

I mean there are packages of what you want to do.
Check out this tutorial on Seasonality in R
https://anomaly.io/seasonal-trend-decomposition-in-r/index.html

A fast fourier Transform in R is also explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435777/perform-fourier-analysis-to-a-time-series-in-r/41465250

Comment: hello @Janosch, thanks for answer :-)  ( i will look/try it and feedback results ) thanks

Comment: just small update; (1. link) got how to detect frequencies then use 1 in decompose, it didnt helped much, but was very very good "cornerstone" to multiple repeatable waves from (2. link)-its complicated but progress is happening

Comment: sorry mr. Janosch, both answers were very good, you evend did post very early and provided explanations ..  ofcourse thanks for help, i did upvote answer it helped much, but have only rep for 1 bounty

Answer (score 2):

When you have periodic data, the first thing you should do is to look at it in the [frequency domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_domain).  You can look at the scaled Fourier intensity of the signal in the frequency domain using the `intensity` function in the [`ts.extend` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ts.extend/index.html).  If you look at the scaled intensity for this signal you will see that there is a large intensity spike covering several low-frequencies.

```
#Load the data
DATA <- read.csv('my_data.csv', header = TRUE)

#Compute the Fourier intensity
INT <- ts.extend::intensity(DATA$x)
plot(INT)

#Find the maximum Fourier intensity
INT.ORDER <- order(INT, decreasing = TRUE)
attributes(INT)$names[INT.ORDER[1:5]]
[1] "Freq[5/6294]"  "Freq[15/6294]" "Freq[1/6294]"  "Freq[8/6294]"  "Freq[2/6294]"
```

[image]

As a starting point, you could "model" this type of data using some kind of high-pass filter, which would filter out the low-intensity signals and leave the high-intensity signals.  Filtering of this kind gives a smoothed signal composed of the high-intensity parts, which gives an implicit separation of an estimated signal and estimated noise.  In the plot below the original signal is shown in black and the filtered signal is shown in red.  As you can see, filters of this kind perform poorly at the endpoints of the time-series, but they do a reasonable job of smoothing within the main bulk of the series.

```
#Compute the DFT of the signal
n    <- length(DATA$x)
MEAN <- mean(DATA$x)
SD   <- sd(DATA$x)
DFT  <- fft(DATA$x - MEAN)/(SD*sqrt(n))

#Impose a high-pass filter with cut-off of scaled intensity = 2
INT  <- Mod(DFT)
DFT.FILT <- DFT
DFT.FILT[INT < 2] <- 0
DATA$filtered <- MEAN + SD*Re(fft(DFT.FILT, inverse = TRUE)/sqrt(n))

#Plot the data and filtered data
plot(DATA$x, xlab = 'Time', ylab = 'Value', type = 'l', lty = 1, lwd = 2)
lines(DATA$filtered, col = 'red', lty = 2, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: hello, thanks alot, can I just ask, can this be extened, to plot for example time+400 (i mean, to show how those "sums of sin cos "continue")

Comment: Yes, you could take the filtered DFT and increase its resolution and then extend to a longer series if you wish.  I would be careful in making predictions out of range in this way, since highpass filtering is a classic "overfitting" method.  The present answer is just a teaser to get you started with looking at data in the frequency domain.

Comment: i would be happy to try it :-) but dont know how create it.. can you add code to provide prediction for next 400 points?